# Using Daffodil DFDL to Convert JSON to XML

Tags: json, xml, dfdl

I would like to utilize DFDL (Daffodil) to convert JSON to XML.  I see examples at this location:  https://github.com/DFDLSchemas

I am not seeing an example using something similar to JSON.

Is there example DFDL schemas that would show me how to do this conversion?

I am trying to learn how to utilize Daffodil to convert JSON to XML.